# How to retreive the child Nodes keys only Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Actually i am fetching the data of all the subjects to the listView

which are Pathology and SocialScience.

when i am retreiving the key i am getting ending date , starting date all that too.

How can i get the only the children which have nodes like here pathology and Soil scence.
?

Comment: please add your code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve a node with Firebase, it always retrieves the entire node. There is no way to get a node without its children, or (beyond what a query can do) with a subset of its children.

When you have this need, it typically means that you've mixed two types of data in a single branch. The Firebase documentation recommends [avoiding such data nesting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).

In your case, I'd split the data into two top-level nodes, each with the same keys for its children. Something like:

```
ExamInfos: {
  "-MV8_...": {
    "endingDate": ...,
    "examType": ...,
    "programme": ...,
    "startingDate": ...
  }
},
ExamSugbjects: {
  "-MV8_...": {
    "PATHOLOGY": { ... },
    "SOIL SCIENCE": { ... }
  }
}
```

Now you can get all subjects for an exam, by loading its `ExamSubjects` child node, all other info by loading its `ExamInfos` child node, and you can load both if needed. Contrary to what many devs initially expect, this won't take much more time, as Firebase can [pipeline the requests over its existing web socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

---

As a separate recommendation, I'd also consider storing the dates in a format that allows more ordering and filtering. The most common format for this is `2021-03-07` for March 7, 2021.